# jquery to split a list into three columns

Tags: jquery

I was browsing around and found the code here:
http://codepen.io/jawittdesigns/pen/zhCrv
to break a list up into three columns.

I will repost the jquery code below:

```
$(function($) {
var num_cols = 3,
container = $('.split-list'),
listItem = 'li',
listClass = 'sub-list';
container.each(function() {
    var items_per_col = new Array(),
    items = $(this).find(listItem),
    min_items_per_col = Math.floor(items.length / num_cols),
    difference = items.length - (min_items_per_col * num_cols);
    for (var i = 0; i < num_cols; i++) {
        if (i < difference) {
            items_per_col[i] = min_items_per_col + 1;
        } else {
            items_per_col[i] = min_items_per_col;
        }
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < num_cols; i++) {
        $(this).append($('<ul ></ul>').addClass(listClass));
        for (var j = 0; j < items_per_col[i]; j++) {
            var pointer = 0;
            for (var k = 0; k < i; k++) {
                pointer += items_per_col[k];
            }
            $(this).find('.' + listClass).last().append(items[j + pointer]);
        }
    }
});
});
```

The code splits the below list into three columns correctly, but my div is displayed as a four column, rather than below the listed items (what I want). I'm new to jquery and just looking at the code, it seems that only the items in the class "split-list" should be affected... Could someone explain to me what is going on? Here is a fiddle to show the unwanted behavior: http://jsfiddle.net/EebVF/5/

```
<ul class="split-list">
   <li>list Item 1</li>
   <li>list Item 2</li>
   <li>list Item 3</li>
   <li>list Item 4</li>
   <li>list Item 5</li>
   <li>list Item 6</li>
</ul>
<div>I should be below the three columns.</div>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Add `clear: both` to your styles for that div. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/scrowler/EebVF/59/). *edit* to answer your question about why this is happening, the jQuery plugin looks like its setting float attributes to all those li items. Normally after a section of floated elements you need to clear the formatting (clear: both) to continue as normal. If you inspect the elements you'll see that the `ul` elements have `float: left` added to them

Comment: so it seems it is solved, right? 
@scrowler post it as an answer and tell pomegranate to accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR:**

Add `clear: both` to the styles for that div.

---

To answer your question about why this is happening, the jQuery plugin is setting `float` attributes to all of the `ul` elements it creates. Normally after a section of floated elements you need to [clear the formatting](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_clear.asp) (`clear: both`) to continue as normal.

The default option for the `clear` attribute is `none` (definition below), so the div below will automatically be allowing floating elements to align with it unless you tell the browser not to.

> none: Default. Allows floating elements on both sides

If you inspect the elements you'll see that the `ul` elements have `float: left` added to them.

Fix:

```
<ul class="split-list">
   <li>list Item 1</li>
   <li>list Item 2</li>
   <li>list Item 3</li>
   <li>list Item 4</li>
   <li>list Item 5</li>
   <li>list Item 6</li>
</ul>
<div style="clear: both">I *WILL* be below the three columns.</div>
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/scrowler/EebVF/59/)